# Nintex licence in sharepoint 2010

Tags: nintex

This is regarding nintex license in Sharepoint 2010. I would like to know when production server nintex license expires?

Comment: If I don't renew license, will work flows will work in SP 2010?

Comment: I'll check my magic crystal ball. But to be honest, you should contact Nintex support and have this dialog with them. No one here can know when your license expires.

Answer (score 0):

When the license expires, whether in Production or Non-Production servers, all Nintex running components (workflow/forms) are disabled. This can then be resumed after renewing the license.

However, before expiry, you get plenty of reminders/messages on your running Nintex instances, prompting you about the expiry message.

Mode details can be found [here](https://community.nintex.com/thread/4871).